# Pass model name as a parameter in function and use its methods like "$this-> $model_name->method()" codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, code-injection

How can I create a method to fill a dropdown reading specific table with specific model, and then get specific column of that table to fill dropdown?

for instance if I have a model person 
I have

```
function get_all_id($id,$table) {
    $this->db->from($table);
    $this->db->order_by($id, "asc");
    $q = $this->db->get();
    return $q;
}
```

then If I need to fill lets say a dropdown with last name field...I would use it as

```
$this->load->model('person_model');
$row = $this->person_model->get_all_id('id_person','tbl_person');
foreach ($row->result() as $val) 
$result .= "<option value='". $val->last_name."'>".$val->last_name."</option> \n" ;
```

then I just echo that on view.

How can I do a function that receives **model name**, **table_name** and specific field I need as parameter?
like

```
function fill_dropdown($model_name, $id, $table_name, $field){
    $this->load->model($model_name);
    $row = $this->  $model_name  ->get_all_id($id,$table_name);
    foreach ($row->result() as $val) 
    return "<option value='". $val->$field."'>".$val->$field."</option> \n" ;

}
```

As this is not allowed: `$row = $this->  $model_name`

Comment: Could you save model name in a variable?

Comment: Do not know how to code that

Comment: Try this: `$row = $this->{$model_name}->get_all_id($id,$table_name);`

Comment: What's the purpose of the extra models, if you are already passing table and field names as parameters into 1 model function?

Comment: To get specific all rows of a particular field in specific table called in a specific model

Comment: If you pass field and table parameters to 1 model function, it will give the exact same result as calling it from the other model function. I see no benefit in repeating code.

Comment: well, the issue here is there is a whole system that has that as backbone, however doing this some code will be not repeated and be more readeble

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you load the model you can assign it a generic name that you can then use to reference that model in your code.

```
function fill_dropdown($model_name, $id, $table_name, $field){
    $this->load->model($model_name, 'myModel');
    $row = $this->myModel->get_all_id($id,$table_name);
    foreach ($row->result() as $val) 
    return "<option value='". $val->$field."'>".$val->$field."</option> \n" ;

}
```

See the "[Loading a Model](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/models.html#loading)" section of the [user guide](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/models.html).

Comment: One more question is it valid to use `$val->$field` or we need to add `$val->{$field}`

Comment: @cMinor `$val->$field` is valid from a php standpoint, see http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/n2f-gdz